# WeakReference Leak using wpf dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, dispatcher, weak-references

I'm having issues with the performance of a WPF application. Using a profiler I can see that in one of my windows, there are instances being created and kept alive over time, and so the memory used grows too.

This is a capture of a graph from the profiler with the number of live instances (red) and memory consumption (pink).

[image]

The application receives no input from the user in those 15 mins and the type of the instances being created is WeakReference. In other posts I saw that leaks of WeakReference can be caused by a bad usage of event registration, but in this case i'm having only one window opened during the profile session so I suspect it can be a problem with the dispatcher.

I use the dispatcher to capture an image from a webcam, do some processing and show the processed image in the WPF Window this way:

```
private delegate void AnalyzeImage();
Image<Bgr, byte> image;
String imagesFolder = "..\\..\\"

public MyWindow(){
    InitializeComponent();
    AnalyzeImage fetcher = new AnalyzeImage(this.getCard);
    fetcher.BeginInvoke(null, null);
}


private void UpdateInterface()
{
    ListReadCards.Items.Add(cardName);
    imageBackup.Source = ImageProcessor.ToBitmapSource(image);
    AnalyzeImage fetcher = new AnalyzeImage(this.getCard);
    fetcher.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    if (card > cardsToRead)
    {
        finished = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}


public void getCard()
{
    Image<Gray, byte> thresholdImage;
    cardName = ImageProcessor.getCard(capture.QueryFrame(), out thresholdImage, out image, imagesFolder);
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new AnalyzeImage(UpdateInterface));
    if (cardName != null)
    {
        hand.Add(cardName);
        card++;
    }
}
```

Already tried to execute `ImageProcessor.getCard` and `ImageProcessor.ToBitmapSource` 100 million times in a for loop to check if there is a problem in those calls, but instances and memory don't grow in that case.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but your calling a `BeginInvoke` on the fetcher without an `EndInvoke`. It could easily be `fetcher.BeginInvoke(fetcher.EndInvoke, null);`

Comment: @Silvermind I tried it, but didn't solve the problem

Comment: Could you show us the code from the `AnalyzeImage fetcher`?